# Javascript serializing CDATA with XMLSerializer

Tags: javascript, xml, internet-explorer, cdata

I am trying to find a cross browser way to serialize an SVG document containing CDATA.

My code works well on Chrome and Firefox, but on Internet Explorer the CDATA is serialized as text instead of a CDATA section. Here is my implementation so far:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<xml></xml>',  "application/xml");
var cdata = xml.createCDATASection('Some data & some more');
svg.appendChild(cdata);
log("Node Type: " + cdata.nodeName)
log("SVG: " + new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg));


// Utility function for output
function log(s) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  if (output) {
    output.innerHTML += new Option(s).innerHTML + '<br>';
  } else {
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```

On Chrome and Firefox the output of the XMLSerializer looks as expected:
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><![CDATA[Some data & some more]]></svg>`

But on Internet Explorer the CDATA is written as a simple text node:
`<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">Some data &amp; some more</svg>`

I tried adding wrapping the CDATA section's data in "<![CDATA[" and "]]>", but this does not work because it will be escaped. Is there anything I can do to make Internet Explorer write the CDATA section correctly?

*Note: The Snippet does not work in Internet Explorer if embedded into Stackoverflow, but it works as as standalone file.*

Comment: Are you looking at console output here, or at what you have written into an element on the page using .innerHTML? I don’t see you escaping the data anywhere in the latter case, so have you verified that _that_ is not actually the issue – browser parsing this as HTML, and while doing so maybe swallowing the “tags”?

Comment: `new Option(s).innerHTML` does the escaping for the output and if I write to console it the output looks the same. I am pretty sure nothing is swallowed by browser parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a hacky solution, which is not really satisfying, but it works.

Before serialization the `cdata`'s data is surrounded by a start and end marker (I am using `__CDATA` and `CDATA__` and after serialization a regular expression is used to replace the markers (and optional CDATA opening and end tags) by CDATA opening and end tags.

Optionally browser sniffing could be used to detect if this hack is necessary at all.

Here is the modified example:

```js
var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
var xml = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<xml></xml>',  "application/xml");
var cdata = xml.createCDATASection('Some data & some more');
// Add markers
cdata.data = "__CDATA" + cdata.data + "CDATA__";
svg.appendChild(cdata);
var svgStr = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(svg);
// Replace markers (and already existing CDATA start and end tags)
svgStr = svgStr.replace(/(?:<\!\[CDATA\[)?__CDATA(.*?)CDATA__(?:\]\]>)?/g, '<![CDATA[$1]]>');

log("SVG: " + svgStr);



// Utility function for output
function log(s) {
  var output = document.getElementById('output');
  if (output) {
    output.innerHTML += new Option(s).innerHTML + '<br>';
  } else {
    console.log(s);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="output"></div>
```